# How to check attribute exists in WooCommerce jquery found_variation event

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, variant

Within WooCommerce, we want to display additional price information when quantity changes, but only if a variant has a specific attribute associated with it. Is there a way to do this based on the variant object supplied as part of the found_variation event?

```js
$(document).on( 'found_variation', 'form.cart', function( event, variation ) {
/* Your code */           
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting the additional price information from?  You'll need an Ajax call if it resides in the database (you make your Ajax call in the function body).

Anyway, you can access a variation's attributes in the variation object that `found_variation` provides.
To see it, add this to the funtion body (where you currently have `/* Your code */`), and open your developer console to see the output.  Press F12 in Chrome > go to Console tab.

```js
console.log(variation.attributes);
```

The attributes are prefixed with 'attribute_pa_'.

If, for example, you want to display something if a variation has the blue color attribute, you'd do this in the function body:

```js
if (variation.attributes.attribute_pa_color === 'blue') {
    /* code to display HTML elements with additional price information */
}
```

Comment: In my case the attribute was just prefixed with attribute_ but you steered me 99.9% of the way to solving it so very much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help! (in fact, up until seeing your example I didn't know the event also included the variation object - I realised I can refactor my own code)

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles on this and wonders about whether to use attribute_pa_color or attibute_color I just discovered that if you define the attribute as a "global" attribute then it takes the form of attribute_pa_ but if it's just an attribute local to that one product then it is attribute_